# Swagger Codegen: Incorrect package name when generating spring project

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am trying to generate a Spring Boot project using Swagger code generator. I use the following command:

```
swagger-codegen generate \
  -i myapp.yaml \
  -l spring \
  -o myapp-api
  --api-package com.myapp.controllers \
  --model-package com.myapp.model \
  --invoker-package com.myapp \
  --group-id com.myapp \
  --artifact-id myapp \
  --artifact-version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

**Problem:** All classes are properly generated but the configuration classes. They are put to `io.swagger.configuration` package instead of my own package.

**Question:** How to make swagger generate configuration classes to a proper package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring generator has the `configPackage` option to override the `io.swagger.configuration` package name.

```plain
swagger-codegen config-help -l spring


CONFIG OPTIONS
        ...

        configPackage
            configuration package for generated code
```

When running Swagger Codegen from the command line, you can specify language-specific configs as `-Doption=value`, in this case as `-DconfigPackage=your_package`:

```
swagger-codegen generate \
  ...
  -DconfigPackage=com.myapp.configuration
```